# No me reconoce pattern en input de HTML5

Tags: html5

Tengo un problema en un formulario en el recojo datos con input y quiero que solo me recoja dígitos en lugar de letras.
Estoy utilizando una base de datos IndexedDb y me lo guarda en la misma como `null` por el tipo de almacén de objetos que tengo creada.
En el input estoy utilizando pattern para especificar que solo sea numéricos pero no me funciona.

HTML:

```
<form name="f1">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">NºHistoria</label>
        <input type="text" id="dni1" placeholder="dni" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="email">Enter MD</label>
        <input type="text" id="md" placeholder="MD" pattern="[0-9]{0,}"required/><br>
    </div>
</form>
<a href class="button submit" onclick="addprueba(dni1);">Save</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function addprueba() {
    //
    //pruebas
    var active2 = dataBase.result; //conector con la base de datos
    var data1 = active2.transaction(["pacientes"], "readwrite"); //array ,modo de transacción
    var objectDb = data1.objectStore("pacientes");
    var index1 = objectDb.index("by_dni");
    var request1 = index1.get(calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value));//index1.get(calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value));//md5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value);//

    request1.onsuccess = function () {

        md1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#md").value);
        slv1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#slv").value);
        var result = request1.result;
        tipo1 = result.tipo;
        //alert('hola'+tipo1);
        if( md1 >16.33 && tipo1 == "O" )//octopus
        {
            //alert('estoy aquí');
            slv1 = slv1 + ((md1-16.33)/0.84);
            //alert('hola'+slv1);
            //alert(slv1);
        }else if( md1 <-17.35 && tipo1 =="H"){ //humfrey
            slv1 = slv1 + ((md1+17.35)/0.84)
            //alert(md1);
            //alert(slv1);
        }

        var active = dataBase.result; //conector con la base de datos
        var data = active.transaction(["pruebas"], "readwrite"); //array ,modo de transacción
        var objectDb1 = data.objectStore("pruebas");
        var index = objectDb1.index("by_dni");
        var request = index.get(calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value));//
        //index.get(calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value));
        //aquí le pasaría el dni recogido en la otra página y le añadiría
        var request = objectDb1.put({
            md: document.querySelector("#md").value,
            slv: slv1,
            mes: document.querySelector("#mes").value,
            anyo: document.querySelector("#anyo").value,
            orde: parseFloat(( parseFloat(document.querySelector("#mes").value))+(12* parseFloat((document.querySelector("#anyo").value)-2000))), dni:calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value)//calcMD5(document.querySelector("#dni1").value)
        });
        request.onerror = function (e) {
            alert(request.error.name + '\n\n' + request.error.message);
        };

        data.oncomplete = function (e) {

            document.querySelector('#md').value = '';
            document.querySelector('#slv').value = '';
            document.querySelector('#mes').value = '';
            document.querySelector('#anyo').value = '';
            alert('The medical test has been created correctly');
            //passdata(document.querySelector("#dni1").value);
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Pues si quieres que tu input solo reconozca solo enteros debes cambiar el tipo `input`, es decir; la propiedad `type="text"` por `type="number"`. Te dejo la respuesta debajo.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de `addprueba` para saber cómo verificas los inputs, lo que creo que está pasando es que cuándo pides el valor del input cómo no pertenece al pattern indicado te devuelve null, también puedes agregar el `type=number` para las validaciones.

Comment: Añado arriba la función addprueba porque los campos de md y slv pueden ser tanto enteros como decimales.

Comment: @AaronVC acabo de editar mi respuesta añadiendo un pattern para enteros y decimales. Revisalo a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Ah vale muchas gracias no lo había visto.Es compatible con la función que puso @Mitsu Gami añadiendo el pattern??? Porque probé la función y perfecto excepto que no funciona con decimales.

Answer (score 2):

Cambia la propiedad `type` en el `input`, te dejo el código

```
<input type="number" id="dni1" placeholder="dni" required/>
```

Con este cambio en la propiedad `type` el input solo deberá reconocer enteros.

Answer (score 2):

Como te comentan si quieres usar solo numeros sería mejor usar el

```
<input type="number" />
```

Sin embargo si tienes que usar obligatoriamente el pattern en un input text, puedes usar la expresion regular: `\d*`

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

`\d` es la expresión regular para los números, * significa que acepta más de un numero.

Si quieres restringir la cantidad de números ingresados podrías usar el atributo `maxlength`

**EDIT AGREGADO VALIDACIÓN JS**

Si quieres que acepte enteros y decimales puedes usar el siguiente pattern:

```js
function validarNumero(){
  var numero = $("#demo").val();
  if (!numero.match(/^(\d+)(\.\d+)?$/)) {
    alert("Incorrecto no es un decimal");
  } else {
    alert("Correcto es un decimal");
  }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
<input id="demo" type="text" pattern="\d+(\.\d+)?" required=""/>
<input type="submit" value="validar html"/>
</form>
<button onclick="validarNumero()">Validar JS</button>
```

Comment: No me pilla el pattern me sigue introduciendo letras y números.Lo único que me funciona es la función que me puso el compañero @Mitsu Gami pero el problema es que necesito introducir decimales.

Comment: @AaronVC realmente no se que porque no te funciona, pero acabo de agregar un snnippet funcional haciendo validacion con patterns en html y js, pruebalo a ver si te funciona. Al dar click en validar html no hace nada ya que no se permite el envio de formulario en los snippets, pero significa que el formato es correcto, cuando pones una cadena incorrecta salta el mensaje de ingresar una cadena con el formato requerido.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sería más útil **no permitir en tiempo real** que se ingresen letras. Por ejemplo, para evitar que se ingresen letras o más de 8 caracteres (DNI Peruano):

```js
function validarDni(e) {
 if(e.value === '') { return; }
 var lastchar = e.value.substring(e.value.length - 1);
    if(isNaN(lastchar) || e.value.length > 8) {
       e.value = e.value.substring(0, e.value.length - 1);
    }
}
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #777;
  padding: .45rem .55rem;
  transition: border-color .18s ease;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 187, 255, .5);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dni" onkeyup="validarDni(this)" onkeydown="validarDni(this)" />
```

#### Actualización por pedido

En caso quieras decimales, si bien se puede agregar código a la función existente para que funcione, creo es más sencillo si usas `pattern` (expresiones regulares):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" required />
```

Si quieres algo más dinámico, por ejemplo que se informe que el valor que se está ingresando es incorrecto o correcto (en tiempo real), puedes aprovechar la API de validación:

```js
function validateControl(e) {
  if(!e.checkValidity()) {
    if(e.classList.contains('valid')) {
      e.classList.remove('valid');
    }
    e.classList.add('invalid');
  } else {
    if(e.classList.contains('invalid')) {
      e.classList.remove('invalid');
    }
    e.classList.add('valid');
  }
}

function prueba(dni) {
   if(!document.querySelector('form').checkValidity()) {
      alert('El formulario tiene errores');
   }
}
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: .5rem;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
button {
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  padding: .46rem .75rem;
  transition: all .18s ease;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border-color: #2980b9;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: rgb(0,187,255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,187,255,.5);
  outline: none;
}
.valid {
  border-color: #27ae60 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(39,174,96,.4) !important;
}
.invalid {
  border-color: #e74c3c !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(231,76,60,.4) !important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="dni" onkeyup="validateControl(this)" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" required title="Ingrese solo números" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="prueba(dni)">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Podrías también mostrar un popup mostrando el erro con más detalle, etc.

Comment: Tu script tiene un pequeño error, si mantienes presionada una tecla, te deja ingresar  letras o más de 8 números tranquilamente, ya que solo elimina el ultimo caracter.

Comment: @JuanPinzón Gracias, era por que usaba `keyup` ya que el evento se dispara cuando la tecla se levanta (release). Con `keydown` creo no pasa. Prueba de nuevo a ver.

Comment: Así ya funciona mejor, sin embargo de esa manera si ingresas los 8 números y tecleas una letra, el ultimo caracter permite que sea una letra.

Comment: Disculpa la demora. Gracias por informarme, ya está corregido.

Comment: Buenas tardes, Muchas gracias antes que nada ni cuantas respuestas jajaja se agradece lo pruebo y os digo.Me gusta la función que informa a tiempo real que no permita introducir letras.

Comment: Muchas gracias la función tira perfecta pero de que manera puede permitir que se introduzcan decimales?? Porque en algún campo del formulario es necesario. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Se puede sí, pero en ese caso sería mejor usar `pattern` para validar en el submit.

Comment: el pattern en este caso no me funciona solo me funciona tu función javascript.

Comment: Es porque usas una expresión regular incorrecta. He actualizado mi respuesta, pruébalo.

Comment: @AaronVC He actualizado mi respuesta una vez más para que lo entiendas mejor.

Comment: Perfecto me muestra los colores de verde y rojo en función de si es número o no pero cuando voy a ejecutar el botón Save con la función addprueba() me lo ejecuta igual introduciéndomelo en la base de datos.

Comment: Ahora probe tu ejemplo y si funciona pero necesito que cuando pulso sobre el botón se llame a la función addprueba() entonces le añadí <button type="submit" onclick="addprueba(dni1);">Save</button> y me guarda sea números o no.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41630/discussion-between-mitsu-gami-and-aaron-vc).